# Showing answer to 2 decimal places in code c++

Tags: c++

I am writing a Cube class which I have to calculate volume also. The class can have a user input of FLOAT length, width and height in between minimum 1 to maximum 45.00. Otherwise if user inputs any other numbers its all sides would be 1.

so it will be like

```
#define LIMIT_UNDER 1
#define LIMIT_UPPER 45.00

class Cube {
  float height;
  float width;
  float length;

public:
  // Write setter getters here

  // default constructor
  Cube() {
    // default constructor puts default values
    height = width = length = LIMIT_UNDER;


  Cube(float cHeight, float cWidth, float cLength) {
    height = cHeight;
    width = cWidth;
    length = cLength;
  }

  float getVolume() {
    return height * width * length;
  }
};

int main() {
  // Default constructor called
  Cube cube;

  // Parametized called
  Cube cube2(2.00f, 2.57f, 5.40f);

  // Show volume to 2
  // decimal places as 45.00
  // is limit that has two decimal places
  cout << getVolume() << fixed << setPrecision(2);
  )
```

My question is about should I use all floats (5.40f etc) to two decimal places and the calculations? As I did in main using setPrecision function

Thanks please help

Comment: It's up to your service. If you are trying to get more precision, it would be better to use only one precision at the last (at the print function)

Comment: There is no correct answer in your answer. Just preference.

Comment: One detail: You should set the precision of cout *before* outputting the value,

Comment: It's up to you.  `5.4f` and `5.40f` are equivalent.     There is a quibble in that floating point types cannot exactly represent all multiples of `0.01` (there is rounding error) but that doesn't need to affect your choices on how you supply literal values (e.g. `5.40f` versus `5.4f`) or the precision you set for outputting them.